# MERN Stack - TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm following along with Traversy Media's MERN Stack, Front To Back Course. I am trying to set up the login part of the app. I made sure my code is exactly the same as his. But I am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` and he is not.

I've been reading on github and people said it is a problem with reactstrap, something to do with dependencies? It's way over my head. I tried running npm ci, I tried altering the json-package-lock file, I tried making an npm-shrinkwrap file, etc, as described here https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1373 and here https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1374 but nothing is working so far, it produces the exact same error.

authActions.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
import setAuthToken from "../utils/setAuthToken";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER } from "./types";

// Register User
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then(res => history.push("/login"))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};

// Login - Get User Token
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      // Set token to ls
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};

// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded
  };
};
```

Dashboard.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getCurrentProfile } from "../../actions/profileActions";
import Spinner from "../common/Spinner";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCurrentProfile();
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    const { profile, loading } = this.props.profile;

    let dashboardContent;

    if (profile === null || loading) {
      dashboardContent = <Spinner />;
    } else {
      // Check if logged in user has profile data
      if (Object.keys(profile).length > 0) {
        dashboardContent = <h4>TODO: DISPLAY PROFILE</h4>;
      } else {
        // User is logged in but has no profile
        dashboardContent = (
          <div>
            <p className="lead text-muted">Welcome {user.name}</p>
            <p>You have not yet setup a profile, please add some info</p>
            <Link to="/create-profile" className="btn btn-lg btn-info">
              Create Profile
            </Link>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className="dashboard">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <h1 className="display-4">Dashboard</h1>
              {dashboardContent}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getCurrentProfile }
)(Dashboard);
```

expected: loads a page that I can log into, and then when I log in it should say "Welcome, `user.name`. You have not yet setup a profile, please add some info"

actual results:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
Dashboard.render
src/components/dashboard/Dashboard.js:23

  20 |   dashboardContent = <Spinner />;
  21 | } else {
  22 |   // Check if logged in user has profile data
> 23 |   if (Object.keys(profile).length > 0) {
     | ^  24 |     dashboardContent = <h4>TODO: DISPLAY PROFILE</h4>;
  25 |   } else {
  26 |     // User is logged in but has no profile
```

Also, after leaving it alone for a while, if I come back to it, it loads the page where I can log in, but when I use the log in info for a user that I registered in the database, it gives me this error:

```
(anonymous function)
src/actions/authActions.js:39
  36 |     .catch(err =>
  37 |       dispatch({
  38 |         type: GET_ERRORS,
> 39 |         payload: err.response.data
  40 |       })
  41 |     );
  42 | };
```

And when I reload it goes back to giving me the other error shown above (the `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. The most obvious is how you're checking `profile`:

`if (profile === null || loading)`

What I believe is happening is that `profile` is being set as `undefined` and `loading` is being set as `false`, and therefore, it's passing the `if` statement.

Instead, set `profile` initially to be an empty object `{}`. Then, you can use lodash's `isEmpty()` function to check if it's still empty. This will also keep your `propTypes` validation as 1:1. If it's an object, it stays an object. If it's a string, it stays a string, and so on. Again keep it 1:1.

In addition, when type checking the props, describe the `shape` of the `object`. Sometime down the line, you'll mostly like use `eslint`, and it'll throw errors about using generic descriptors like `Proptypes.array` and `Proptypes.object`. While this may seem overkill, it can highlight errors within your object if a property differentiates from the described shape.

**Working codesandbox**:

[image: Edit Restructured App]

---

This example includes some advanced/intermediate code usage, so I'd imagine some of it won't make sense. If you have questions, feel free to ask.

Used in this code example: [ES6 object desctucturing](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f), [fat arrow functions with simplified returns](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html), [fat arrow class properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), [the spread operator](https://codeburst.io/a-simple-guide-to-destructuring-and-es6-spread-operator-e02212af5831) and the [ternary operator](https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-conditional-ternary-operator-explained-cac7218beeff).

Refactored and simplified version of your code...

**containers/Dashboard**

```
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getCurrentProfile } from "../../actions/profileActions";
import DisplayUser from "../../components/DisplayUser";
import DisplaySignUp from "../../components/DisplaySignUp";
import Spinner from "../../components/Spinner";

// using a PureComponent because we're not utilizing state, 
// but we're utilizing the "componentDidMount" lifecycle
class Dashboard extends PureComponent { 
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.getCurrentProfile(1);
  }

  // the below can be read like so:
  // if "isLoading" is true...  then show a spinner
  // else if "currentUser" is not empty... then display the user details
  // else show a signup message
  render = () => (
    this.props.isLoading ? (    
      <Spinner />  
    ) : !isEmpty(this.props.currentUser) ? ( 
      <DisplayUser currentUser={this.props.currentUser} /> /
    ) : (
      <DisplaySignUp />  
    )
}

// describing the shape of the "currentUser" object 
// notice that there aren't any required declarations 
// within the object itself because "currentUser" is initially 
// an empty object; however, when it's not empty, it should 
// follow this structure
Dashboard.propTypes = {
  getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  currentUser: PropTypes.shape({ 
    id: PropTypes.number,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    username: PropTypes.string,
    email: PropTypes.string,
    address: PropTypes.shape({
      street: PropTypes.string,
      suite: PropTypes.string,
      city: PropTypes.string,
      zipcode: PropTypes.string,
      geo: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string)
    }),
    phone: PropTypes.string,
    website: PropTypes.string,
    company: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string)
  }).isRequired,
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  state => ({
    currentUser: state.profile.currentUser,
    isLoading: state.profile.isLoading
  }),
  { getCurrentProfile }
)(Dashboard);
```

**reducers/profileReducer**

```
import * as types from "../types";

const initialState = {
  currentUser: {}, // setting currentUser initially as an empty object
  isLoading: true // setting isLoading initially as a boolean
};

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case types.SET_SIGNEDIN_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentUser: { ...payload },
        isLoading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```